# Soroban CLI Error: Missing Result in Successful Response

Tags: stellar-sdk, smart-contract

I'm encountering an error while deploying a Soroban contract using the Soroban CLI. Here's the command I'm using:

```
soroban contract deploy \
  --wasm target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/hello_soroban.wasm \
  --source alice \
  --network futurenet
```

error: Missing result in successful response

---

I'm encountering an error while deploying a Soroban contract using the Soroban CLI. Here's the command I'm using:

soroban contract deploy
--wasm target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/hello_soroban.wasm
--source alice
--network futurenet

error: Missing result in successful response

[image]